# DataTables Calculate Column Total Based on Another Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datepicker

Using Datatables 1.10.19

I have five columns in my table, `column 2` contains prices, `column 5` contains a string. I want to calculate the total of column 2 *where column 5 equals 'Cash'*.

I also want to perform the calculation based on a date range. How can I achieve this?

I've tried the following but it doesn't work like I want. It successfully calculates the total, but not based on any filter. It simply totals **all** the values in column 2.

```
$('.date-range-filter').change(function() {

    // get all values in column 2
    var cashTotalData = api.search('Cash').column(2, {
        page: 'all'
    }).data();

    // calculate all values
    var cashTotalValue = cashTotalData.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
    }, 0).toFixed(2);

    console.log(cashTotalValue); // this displays the correct total of *all* values in column 2, but not the total based on my date range

    $('#records').DataTable().draw();
});
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you want a `.search()`, I think you want a `.filter()`, but I couldn't figure out how to do it. The example I've included below just loops through the rows and totals the dollar amount.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var table = $("#table").DataTable();
    $('.date-range-filter').click(function() {
        let cashTotalValue = 0;

        table.rows().eq(0).each(function(index){
            var row = table.row( index );
            console.log(row.data());
            // the "type" column is #5, but arrays are 0 based, so subtract one
            if (row.data()[4] == 'Cash') {
                // the "amount" column is #2, but arrays are 0 based, so subtract one
                cashTotalValue += parseInt(row.data()[1]);
            }
        });

        console.log(cashTotalValue.toFixed(2)); // this displays the correct total of *all* values in column 2, but not the total based on my date range
        alert(cashTotalValue.toFixed(2)); // this displays the correct total of *all* values in    
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Transaction</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Type</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>11/15/2018</td>
            <td>Cash</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>11/15/2018</td>
            <td>Credit</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>11/16/2018</td>
            <td>Cash</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>11/16/2018</td>
            <td>Credit</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" class="date-range-filter" value="Click"/>
```

Comment: This does filter like you want. It only totals the values in column 5 where the value in column 2 is "Cash".

Comment: @TheOrdinaryGeek I changed the answer to a code snippet, so you can run it here.Thanks for giving me the opportunity to research code snippets on SO.

Comment: Thanks @bcr666 that's much closer, i've updated the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/24t6w5fz/. Do you know how I would get the total cash & card values to change dynamically as I filter the table?